# Python: convert np array os sec to datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib

I have np array or ints, each represent time since epoch (like 1513003977)
I would like to plot it as dates, and found out you can do it in x the dates are in datetime.datetime format
for can i convert the whole array into datetime?

It is possible to call `plt.plot(dates,values)` with dates being a list of `datetime.datetime` objects. The plot will include xticks in a format like `'%Y-%m-%d'` and as you zoom in, automatically change to one that shows hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: `import datetime;
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1513003977)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This question is a bit different - it is dealing with the epoch timestamps being in a numpy array, not just a single value.

Comment: @lxop Sure, which other question do you want to mark this as duplicate of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a numpy array of timestamps `dates`, you can do the following

```
ticks = dates.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
plt.plot(ticks, values)
```

That does two things: first it reinterprets the integer timestamps as numpy's datetime format (the `[s]` specifies that the units are seconds).

Then, `array.tolist()`, when called on a `datetime64` array, returns a list of `datetime.datetime` objects, which matplotlib can then use for plotting as you desire.